# How to get warning massage when clicking close(X) button of browser with tabs in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

How to get a warning massage if i accidently click the close button of the chrome browser which have multiple tabs opened at that time?
I am a regular user of Crome and having this problem while using it. I normally open multiple tabs inside a single browser but sometimes i accidently click the close button of browser and as soon as the button is clicked crome does't give any warning issue about multiple active tabs and close the entire window.

Is the end user like me is browsing on normal crome window then he can open the websites again by checking the web history but if he is browsing inside private browser then he can't do anything(this happens with me very regularly because i normally browse in private browser). On the other hand if you accidently click the close button in mozilla which have multiple tabs open it throws a warning massage to the user and asks for his wish.

Answer (score 0):

Go find an extension called "Keep One Pinned Tab". It may not be exactly the function you need, but if you search for other extensions, I am sure there is such an extension that does just that. If you can't find one, I suggest to learn how to develop extensions and make one yourself, you can share it with others when it's done.